# Add run-only users to Flow via a List

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, power-automate, flow

As I was looking for a way to share a Flow, which is ran on **List A**, to multiple users without sending an email, I found out I can share the Flow using a SharePoint list (from my understanding, this will share it with users having **Edit** permissions on the list).

I tried adding a list (**List B**) which the account has **Edit** permissions but I don't see the flow in the **Automate** menu, neither if I give the user **Full Control** rights on the list.
(And yes, I see the Flow when adding the user directly in the Run-Only users interface)

According to the documentation, the list (**List B**) used by the Run-Only users interface only requires that the user has **Edit** permissions on the list (**List B**) to be visible on the list used by the Flow (**List A**)

[image]

Comment: Did you create the flow on **list A** and now trying to add same flow on **list B**?

Comment: I created the Flow on **List A**, but using the **List B** for the Run-Only permissions. I added a screenshot in the edit of the post.